# Parsing a code block with EBNF expression

Tags: java, compiler-construction, grammar, ebnf, cocor

I am using CocoR to generate a java-like scanner/parser:
I'm having some troubles in creating a EBNF expression to match a codeblock:

I'm assuming a code block is surrounded by two well-known tokens: 
<& and &>
example:

```
public method(int a, int b) <&  
various code  
&>
```

If I define a nonterminal symbol

```
codeblock = "<&" {ANY} "&>"
```

If the code inside the two symbols contains a '<' character the generated compiler will not handle it thus giving a syntax error.

Any hint?

Edit:

```
COMPILER JavaLike
CHARACTERS

nonZeroDigit  = "123456789".
digit         = '0' + nonZeroDigit .
letter        = 'A' .. 'Z' + 'a' .. 'z' + '_' + '$'.

TOKENS
ident = letter { letter | digit }.

PRODUCTIONS
JavaLike = {ClassDeclaration}.
ClassDeclaration ="class" ident ["extends" ident] "{" {VarDeclaration} {MethodDeclaration }"}" .
MethodDeclaration ="public" Type ident "("ParamList")" CodeBlock.
Codeblock = "<&" {ANY} "&>".
```

I have omitted some productions for the sake of simplicity.
This is my actual implementation of the grammar. The main bug is that it fails if the code in the block contains one of the symbols '>' or '&'.

Answer (score 1):

Nick, late to the party here ...

A number of ways to do this:

Define tokens for `<&` and `&>` so the lexer knows about them.

You may be able to use a COMMENTS directive

COMMENTS FROM `<&` TO `&>` - quoted as CoCo expects.

Or make hack NextToken() in your scanner.frame file. Do something like this (pseudo-code):

```
if (Peek() == CODE_START)
{
     while (NextToken() != CODE_END)
     {
        // eat tokens
     }
}
```

Or can override the Read() method in the Buffer and eat at the lowest level.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

<s>You can expand the ANY term to include `<&`, `&>`, and another nonterminal (call it ANY_WITHIN_BLOCK say).</s>

Then you just use

```
ANY = "<&" | {ANY_WITHIN_BLOCK} | "&>"
codeblock = "<&" {ANY_WITHIN_BLOCK} "&>"
```

And then the meaning of {ANY} is unchanged if you really need it later.

Okay, I didn't know anything about CocoR and gave you a useless answer, so let's try again.

As I started to say later in the comments, I feel that the real issue is that your grammar might be too loose and not sufficiently well specified.

When I wrote the CFG for the one language I've tried to create, I ended up using a sort of "meet-in-the-middle" approach: I wrote the top-level structure AND the immediate low-level combinations of tokens first, and then worked to make them meet in the mid-level (at about the level of conditionals and control flow, I guess).

You said this language is a bit like Java, so let me just show you the first lines I would write as a first draft to describe its grammar (in pseudocode, sorry. Actually it's like yacc/bison. And here, I'm using your brackets instead of Java's):

```
/* High-level stuff */

program: classes

classes: main-class inner-classes

inner-classes: inner-classes inner-class
             | /* empty */

main-class: class-modifier "class" identifier class-block

inner-class: "class" identifier class-block

class-block: "<&" class-decls "&>"

class-decls: field-decl
           | method

method: method-signature method-block

method-block: "<&" statements "&>"

statements: statements statement
          | /* empty */

class-modifier: "public"
              | "private"

identifier: /* well, you know */
```

And at the same time as you do all that, figure out your immediate token combinations, like for example defining "number" as a float or an int and then creating rules for adding/subtracting/etc. them.

I don't know what your approach is so far, but you definitely want to make sure you carefully specify everything and use new rules when you want a specific structure. Don't get ridiculous with creating one-to-one rules, but never be afraid to create a new rule if it helps you organize your thoughts better.

Comment: how would you define ANY_WITHIN_BLOCK?

Comment: ANY is the "jolly" token in CocoR: it matches every token.

Comment: Sorry, I admit I'm not familiar with CocoR. I'm just writing a pseudocode CFG language. I was assuming you had defined {ANY} but if that's just a catch-all token, then that obviously complicates things. :-) (EDIT: Dang it. lol)

Comment: I give you more details: I can define a character set in this fashion: letter ="A..Z" + "%>" so a letter may be any capital letter or the symbols within "". then I can define a token, which must be defined in terms of the character set. So a token, let's say, word should be defined as: word = letter{letter}

Comment: Ah, and {WHATEVER} means zero or more WHATEVERs?

Comment: Anyway, I guess my point is, I'd go for a more rigorous specification of EXACTLY what should go within a block, without relying on a catch-all token. Unless you can do a set difference (basically, ANY minus two tokens), you'll only end up having more than you want to in your code blocks.

Comment: My approach to CFGs for a language is to just start at the top: A program is a set of statements; a statement is a side-effect expression, a function definition, a function call, or a control flow block; a function definition contains a function signature and a block; a block contains "<&", zero or more STATEMENTS (notice I'm using the nonterminal here), and "&>". Take advantage of CFG recursion to impose better structure on your program. (Note that my grammar also allowed for statements outside of methods, maybe you don't want that if you're doing a Java look-alike)

Comment: Sorry for the late answer: you defined   statements: statements statement| /* empty */ but a) how do you define 'statement'? the definition of method-block would be ok but in this way you are kind of parsing the codeblock too. btw I'll post my attributed grammar, maybe it would be more clear.

Comment: I guess I left statement out of there because I figured that just comes down to how you'd define it (note that my specification is intentionally partial). "statement" is where I would break it down into things like, method-call, assignment, side-effect-expression, whatever. What I'm trying to show you is, don't rely on "any token" in the middle of a block-- be more specific; you want statements, so what constitutes a statement? If you say "assignment" as one possibility (which you probably should), what does that look like? That one would be `assignment: identifier "=" expression` or similar.